# Initialization of GtkApplication - Should I use GObject's "init" or GtkApplication's "startup"?

Tags: c, gtk3, glib

I'm trying to create a GTK-3 Application and in the initialization process I want to check if the GSetting's value is set, otherwise I want to show a "startup" dialog which will be only on the first run visible.

The `GObject`'s has a `_init` suffix which can be used for the class initialization. In that case the `MyGtkApplication` will be constructed, which is based on `GtkApplication`. The `GtkApplication` has the `startup`-thing which can be used for the initialization too.

In that example, I still need to implement the `_init` function for GApplicationClass.

```c
GApplicationClass *gapp_class;

gapp_class = G_APPLICATION_CLASS (class);
gapp_class->startup = app_startup;

// This must be always implemented, because the MyGtkApplication is "GtkApplication"-based class.
void app_init(MyGtkApplication *app) {
  // Check and show the modal dialog if key does not exist?
}

// This will overwrite the GApplicatio's "startup".
void app_startup(GApplication *app) {
  // Check and show the modal dialog if key does not exist?
}
```

Currently `app_init` does not have a body.

What is the difference and which one should I use?

Regards,
TheAifam5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init` is basically the constructor of the `GApplication` object. Use it for initializing the object's private data and putting it into a consistent state.

`startup` is invoked when the application starts. In particular, after you have called `g_application_run()` and the main event loop is started, and the application has checked that it is the only instance running. You don't want to show dialog boxes before then, so `startup` is the right place to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have a nice day! :)